# order by date php pagination

Tags: php, sql

I made this script:

```
$query7=mysql_query("select * from events where url='$url'");

while($query8=mysql_fetch_array($query7)){
    $query9=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM events WHERE ordine < " 
                            . $query8['ordine'] . " ORDER BY ordine DESC LIMIT 1");

    while($query10=mysql_fetch_array($query9)){

        if ($query10['titolo']) {
            echo "<a class=\"prev\" href=\"http://localhost:1234/polyxo/" 
                 . $query10['url'] 
                 . "/\" class=\"prev\"><i class=\"fa fa-arrow-left\"></i> " 
                 . $query10['titolo'] . "</a>";
        }
    }
}
```

In this script i have create a prev and next post link on my article, but i have a problem. I'm trying to order by "ordine" but don't work, why? he give me the wrong item.

This is the field "ordine" (date type) in my database:

[image]

the data inside the database looks like this: 2016-02-03

I did research around the web and found this (I think it's a similar situation):

```
WHERE year(added_date) > $today
```

but I did not understand how works

Comment: Field order in the database is not relevant. Inside your 2nd while loop, `echo "SELECT * FROM events WHERE ordine < ".$query8['ordine']." ORDER BY ordine DESC LIMIT 1";` and see if the query looks correct. Run that query manually and see if you get the result you expect.

Comment: explain whats wrong with the code,do you get an error/the dates are not ordered correctly ? also you can combine your queries into 1 - `SELECT * FROM events WHERE url='$url' AND  ordine < " 
                            . $query8['ordine'] . " ORDER BY ordine DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: yes, the order is wrong.

Comment: random order, or the opposite? If opposite then instead of DESC put ASC